# Newbie question about visual studio references

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What is the use of the "References" list in my visual studio project? Why I can still get my project compiled and run it even though I remove all of the references?

When I create a new c# console project, it has a hello world template program, and the References list contains certain references from .Net I think. I removed all of them and the template program still work, why?

The template program has a bunch of usings that were in the references of the project so I thought if I remove all of them nothing will work, but the project still compiled and ran.

This seems to be a very simple question but I can not find anybody answering that online.

Comment: Some references are added by Visual Studio automatically when creating a new project. Those references are the ones that are being used the most. If your program is very simple (like a Hello World program), then you can remove those references because they are not needed. Your code does not use any namespaces/classes of the referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok to answer my question after some research and tests. There are indeed namespaces I can not reference if I don't add them into the References list, the ones that were still working after I removed references were the ones that are implicitly referenced by visual studio.

I have learned that from the links below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92a0c975-e350-4d8d-af8e-36ec0ad6c95c/specific-purpose-of-mscorlib-dll-in-net?forum=clr

Answer (score 0):

Say you need to create an image processing app. But you don't want to, or rather won't be able to create a JPEG encoder/decoder. So you will find a 3rd party library to do the encoding/decoding. And the 3rd party library needs to be put somewhere so that your project can find it. And that is the References folder (it is not really a folder).

Then you can use the 3rd party library's namespace in your own code. And it compiles. But if you remove the references, it won't because VS won't be able to find those namespaces.

If later you decide not to use this library, you will remove your `using` statement and all the relevant code. At this point, if you remove the references, your code will still compile because they are not used at all.

Comment: Thanks for those info, but when it comes to referencing stuff in VS, seems like c++ and c# do stuff differently. In a c++ boilerplate, the project uses other libraries through include directives and there is nothing in the "References" dropdown. For c# boilerplate, instead of include directives I see it has core stuff in the "References" dropdown and that is defining the various using statements I can use right now. Can I understand this phenomena as visual studio treats c++ and c# differently, one through c++'s include approach and another one through the visual studio's "Reference" approach?

Comment: I recall when I was doing stuff with `IHTMLElement`, `IHTMLElement1` etc in C++. I needed to reference `Mshtml.dll` and then did the `pragma` directive. It was ages ago I couldn't remember.